# Using multiple RecyclerView's adapters

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is it possible when we have more than one recycler view adapter in one project?
Each adapter is assigned to 1 activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind one adapter to one `RecyclerView` and even change it later. It doesn't matter how many `RecyclerView`'s and adapters you have.

Comment: @RosaGaghana if the answer helped, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark beside it :)